# How to view apache loaded modules example mod_rewrite, mod_php5 etc using phpinfo

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I have an apache installed on my ubuntu server.
How can I view list of apache loaded modules like mod_rewrite, mod_php5, mod_headers etc using phpinfo function.

Its not showing **Apache Loaded module** section in phpinfo.

Note: Phpinfo function tells that **SERVER API : CGI / FAST CGI**. Also it does not show **APACHE2 HANDLER** SECTION

Comment: When it's not installed as apache module (mod_php), it will subsequently not have knowledge of the Apache config environment.

Comment: @mario So how do I find which modules are installed or not?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/284898/how-to-check-which-apache-modules-are-enabled-installed

Comment: @D555 You might have a module installed but not enabled. Since you are using Ubuntu, you can list all enabled modules with `a2query -m`. To check a module individually: `a2query -m rewrite` for mod_rewrite.